# Alpha channel not rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm switching to Blender from C4D for a while and discovered something super odd on my very first real world project - regardless of what I'm doing, the alpha always renders as pure white when looking in the image viewer in Blender. In Photoshop, After Effects or whatever there simply is no alpha channel. And yes, RGBA is enabled (as it's default setting) and I'm using file formats with alpha channel. After trying the actual scene I just tried rendering the default cube without touching anything with Eevee, Cycles CPU and GPU, with and without denoising. I'm on Blender 3.0.0.What am I missing??? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled transparency in the Film section?

[image]

Comment: OMG. Thanks a lot Crantisz, that was it!! I`m perplexed, though. Why is this ticked off by default? Am I the only person so far who rendered something with an Alpha?? Nonetheless I`m very happy now and can finish the thing :-)))